# Reducing execution time for SUMIFS equivalent

Tags: python, pandas, sumifs

I am trying to reproduce the function SUMIFS in Excel which would be approximately: accumulation1 =SUMIFS(value; $fin$1:$fin$5; ini$1)

what the formula does:
searches for and adds up the values in the end list that correspond to an ini

Example calculation id3 and accumulation 1 :
search or add the values or endPoint(ini = 11) i.e. value of id 1 and id 5 (3+5)=8

And then creating a new accumulation column and restart same computing (I have to do this 1004 times..)

| id | ini | fin | value | accumulation1 | accumulation2 | sumOfAccumulation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 9 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 11 | 12 | 2 | 8 | 0 | 10 |
| 4 | 12 | 13 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 11 |
| 5 | 05 | 11 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 |

I have the code for an accumulation that looks like this for now :

```
    connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_NAME,user=DB_USER, password=DB_PWD, host=DB_HOST, port=DB_PORT)
    cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    
    data = pdsql.read_sql_query("select id_bdcarth, id_nd_ini::int ini, id_nd_fin::int fin, v from tempturbi.tmp_somme_v19",connection)

Endtest=1
 
#loop until Endtest = 0 : 
    #create a new column accumulation  
    for i in data.ini:
        acc=[]
        acc=data.v.loc[data.fin==i] # get values of the upstream segments
        acc=sum(acc) 
        #save acc in accumulation 

    Endtest=data.sum(accumulation)     
    
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

and without saving the calculated results the script takes 129 seconds to run for only which is much slower than Excel. Is there any way to improve the script and make it faster?

what i'm trying to do is to walk along a rivernetwork and compute values :
[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of what the expected output would be on the example table you shared?

Comment: I've updated the table

Comment: Thank you for updating, but I'm still unsure what you are trying to do. Your code is incomplete, for example I don't know what `t` is. I also don't understand the accumulating. In your example table can you explain why there is a `7` for the `id=3` row in the `accumulation1` column?

Comment: my bad i wrote mistakes, it should be better now

Comment: thanks, I understand `accumulation1` column now, but I don't understand `accumulation2` column. why is `id3` `accumulation2` 7?

Comment: also is there a mistake in the `sumOfAccumulation` column for `id3`? should the value be 10 instead of 9?

Comment: yes the correct result is 10

Comment: thanks, and can you please explain why `id3` `accumulation2` equals 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again for clarifying your question. I think I understand now and this approach matches the output you've shown. Please let me know if I misunderstood, and also please let me know if this is faster than your approach. I don't know that it will be

```
import pandas as pd

#Create the test data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'ini': {0: 10, 1: 9, 2: 11, 3: 12, 4: 5},
    'fin': {0: 11, 1: 10, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 11},
    'value': {0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3},
})

#Setup initial values
curr_value_col = 'value'
i = 0
all_value_cols = []

#The groupings stay the same throughout the loops
#so we can just group once and reuse it for speed benefit
gb = df.groupby('fin')

#Loop forever until we break
while True:
    #update the loop number and add to the value col list
    i += 1
    all_value_cols.append(curr_value_col)
    
    #group by fin and sum the value_col values
    fin_cumsum = gb[curr_value_col].sum()
    
    #map the sums to the new column
    next_val_col = 'accumulation{}'.format(i)
    df[next_val_col] = df['ini'].map(fin_cumsum).fillna(0).astype(int)
    
    #If the new column we added sums to 0, then quit
    #(I think this is what you were saying you wanted, but I'm not sure)
    curr_value_col = next_val_col
    if df[curr_value_col].sum() == 0:
        break
        
    
#Get the cumulative sum from the list of columns we've been saving
df['sumOfAccumulation'] = df[all_value_cols].sum(axis=1)
df
```

Comment: wow yes ! this is much faster ! (i get 0.35 seconds for one column) thanks you !

Comment: after some loop i get this msg : 
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df[next_val_col] = df['ini'].map(fin_cumsum).fillna(0).astype(int)

Answer (score 0):

So i've made some modification :

```
loop = [0,1,2]
    #while total != 0:
for total in loop:
    z=z+1
    acc='acc'+str(z)

    # tant que i dans ini
    for i in data.ini:
        v = data.iloc[:,-1:]#get last column
        val = data.v.loc[data.fin==i] 
        val = sum(val) 
        
        #creer colonne et stock valeur
        data[acc] = val
    
    print(data[acc].sum())
    total=total+1
        
print(data)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

(no influence on execution time )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).